# Updating constraints when device orientation change

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton, autolayout

I want to change a button height constraint according to device orientation. I am creating with height constraint. And then I am setting height constraint 60 for landscape mode, 40 for portrait mode. But when I change device orientation, height is not becoming bigger. Where is the problem. Here is my code

```
lazy var nextEpisodeButton: CustomPlayerButton = {
    let nextEpisode = CustomPlayerButton(type: .nextEpisode, backgroundImage: nil)
    nextEpisode.addTarget(self, action: #selector(nextEpisodeTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    nextEpisode.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    nextEpisode.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false
    return nextEpisode
}()

func addNextEpisodeButton() {
    view.addSubview(nextEpisodeButton)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        nextEpisodeButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
        nextEpisodeButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120),
        nextEpisodeButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeRightAnchor, constant: -20),
        nextEpisodeButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeBottomAnchor, constant: -60)
    ])
}

override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.willTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        nextEpisodeButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
    } else {
        nextEpisodeButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    }
    nextEpisodeButton.layoutIfNeeded()

}
```

Answer (score 1):

My way is to do two things:

- Keep the constraints you wish to change in arrays to be activated and deactivated.
- Detect device orientation through a means **other** than traits.

Let's start with the first. And you are off to a good start - the constraints are (a) in code and (b) using anchors. (If by chance you are using IB - Storyboards for others - you'll need to set the changing constraints as `@IBOutlets`.)

It looks like you are wanting this button to be in the right bottom, so let's make those constraints active:

```
nextEpisodeButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeRightAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
nextEpisodeButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeBottomAnchor, constant: -60).isActive = true
```

This will *pin* things properly no matter what the orientation.

Now, let's say you want to change size. You need to put these into *two* arrays:

```
var portraitLayout = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
var landscapeLayout = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

portraitLayout.append(nextEpisodeButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120))
portraitLayout.append(nextEpisodeButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40))

landscapeLayout.append(nextEpisodeButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120))
landscapeLayout.append(nextEpisodeButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60))
```

This sets up a 40x120 button in portrait and a 60x120 button in landscape. This can (should?) be done in `viewDidLoad`. Now it's time to activate/deactivate....

Only **one** array should be active, and you'll need to do one at the time the view is initialized. I'll get to that, but first, let me show two lines of code that is necessary:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(landscapeLayout)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(portraitLayout)
```

You *can* try to add/delete constraints, but this is not only risky and not as easy to maintain, it's not even needed. Simply set all constraints the are constant as `isActive = true`, put the ones that change into arrays, and activate/deactive.

(If you want to animate such changes - I wouldn't for you - then do this and add `UIView.animate(withDuration:)` at the end.)

Now, the rough piece, detecting the orientation.

Apple decided to add trait collections a few years ago. They work well (and this year I finally get why they did it the way they did). But they have *one* serious issue - iPads in full screen mode *always* have a normal size. (I'm writing an iPad only app this year and in split screen mode it *may* be compact.)

Your question stressed orientation, so I'd recommend *not* use trait collection changes. Instead, use `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. For me, this seems to be more reliable - it's the earliest in the view controller lifecycle that I've found. You'll need to do two things... set the initial orientation and detect changes.

Here's my setup. In a `UIView` extension:

```
public func orientationHasChanged(_ isInPortrait:inout Bool) -> Bool {
    if self.frame.width > self.frame.height {
        if isInPortrait {
            isInPortrait = false
            return true
        }
    } else {
        if !isInPortrait {
            isInPortrait = true
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
public func setOrientation(_ p:[NSLayoutConstraint], _ l:[NSLayoutConstraint]) {
    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(l)
    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(p)
    if self.bounds.width > self.bounds.height {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(l)
    } else {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(p)
    }
}
```

`p` and `l` are portrait and landscape respectively. All I do is simply check the bounds and active/deactive appropriately.

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    if initialOrientation {
        initialOrientation = false
        if view.frame.width > view.frame.height {
            isInPortrait = false
        } else {
            isInPortrait = true
        }
        view.setOrientation(p, l)
    } else {
        if view.orientationHasChanged(&isInPortrait) {
            view.setOrientation(p, l)
        }
    }
}
```

This is likely overkill for your needs. I'm basically tracking two things (initial and current orientation) for changes and calling things when needed - `viewWillLayoutSubviews` can be called more than once during a load(?) and for other reasons than an orientation change.

Conclusion:

You are close, but you have a few changes. First, set your constant constraints to `isActive = true` and activate/deactivate the remaining ones as arrays. Second, unless your app is iPhone only (and even then it will still be available for iPad) do not use trait collections, but instead use the view controller lifecycle and the screen bounds.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a reference to `nextEpisodeButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)` constraint somewhere in your ViewController and in `willTransition` callback just change its `constant` value. With your code you are creating and activating a new constraint every time you rotate rather than changing the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

The constraints are persistent. When you are creating a second constraint for the same attribute (in your case the height of a view) and you are activating it, the 2 constraints are conflicting with each other.

So, you need to keep a reference for both of them and activate/deactivate them accordingly:

```
lazy var nextEpisodeButton: CustomPlayerButton = {
    let nextEpisode = CustomPlayerButton(type: .nextEpisode, backgroundImage: nil)
    nextEpisode.addTarget(self, action: #selector(nextEpisodeTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    nextEpisode.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    nextEpisode.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false
    return nextEpisode
}()

private var buttonLandscapeHeightContraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
private var buttonPortraitHeightContraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

func addNextEpisodeButton() {
    view.addSubview(nextEpisodeButton)
    buttonLandscapeHeightContraint = nextEpisodeButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60)
    buttonPortraitHeightContraint = nextEpisodeButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        nextEpisodeButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120),
        nextEpisodeButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeRightAnchor, constant: -20),
        nextEpisodeButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeBottomAnchor, constant: -60)
    ])
    updateButtonHeightConstraint()
}

override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.willTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    
    updateButtonHeightConstraint()
    nextEpisodeButton.layoutIfNeeded()

}

private func updateButtonHeightConstraint() {
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        buttonPortraitHeightContraint?.isActive = false
        buttonLandscapeHeightContraint?.isActive = true
    } else {
        buttonLandscapeHeightContraint?.isActive = false
        buttonPortraitHeightContraint?.isActive = true
    }
}
```

Comment: @tripleyyy which method name did you changed?

Comment: @tripleyyy maybe you having an issue with `isLandscape` property not returning the correct value. This is not so reliable. Is this the case?